# github: "unsupported protocol scheme "" " error

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am trying to push an update to your Github repo, and getting this message:

Post objects/batch: unsupported protocol scheme ""
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://github.com/oursite/ourrepo.git'

I have pushed this same data with the same structure many times with no problems...I tried a few variations (http, https, removing then adding '.git' to the URL) but all result in the same error.
The steps we use:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "comments"
git push https://github.com/oursite/ourrepo.git
(also tried http....just to see, but that did not work)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the remote URL you are using? GitHub remote URLs are in the format `https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git`.

Comment: yes the remote URL is correct, I edited my post...as I mentioned, I have done this the same way several times with no problem.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? How are you supplying your GitHub credentials?

Comment: we are, but  that has never caused any problems in the past..I just pushed to another repo we have using the same method yesterday with no problems, and I have pushed to this repo using the same steps many times before...I am prompted for my username and password in the command prompt, as I always have been.